# Pure Java REST API POST calls to Jenkins /reload or /restart always return status 403 forbidden, but work

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-api

I'm getting an Exception when running this, but *Jenkins actually executes the requested action*:

```
  URL url = new URL("https://somehost.com/jenkins/quietDown");
  HttpURLConnection c= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  c.setRequestMethod("POST");
  c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:apiToken").getBytes()));
  c.getInputStream().close();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://somehost.com/jenkins/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at build.JenkinsClient.main(JenkinsClient.java:102)
```

Testing with Jenkins 2.164.3 and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this gets rid of the Exception:

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

After hours I noticed how the stack trace contained a slightly different URL than the one I was posting to:

```
https://somehost.com/jenkins/
vs
https://somehost.com/jenkins/quietDown
```

It seems like Jenkins answers with a redirect (`302 Found`), which the HttUrlConnections follows by default to read from, which then for some reason caused that exception.

For the longest time, I tried to figure out a way to issue the POST request without calling `connection.getInputStream()`, but that seems to be the only call which actually triggers the request. If anyone knows a different way to issue a POST request with pure Java, please let me know.

I knew my URL and `username:token` stuff was correct because I tested with curl (which doesn't complain, even with the follow redirect option turned on):

```
curl -X POST https://somehost.com/jenkins/quietDown -u admin:token
curl -L -X POST https://somehost.com/jenkins/quietDown -u admin:token
```